# Environment setup for React development

Tags: reactjs, jsx, ejs

[image]I'm trying to setup my windows environment from react development but i am facing an error while typing the commands.
I tried to make Next.js project by copy and pasting (npx create-next-app@latest) from https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project but I'm facing an error.
A snapshot of the error in terminal is attached here.
Please go through it and solve my query.

I tried to create my first React app but faced an error.

Comment: Try doing so using `yarn`, it is very easy to do so using yarn instead of `npx`.